# .NET equivalent of the Ruby ActiveResource Library

Tags: .net, rest

Anyone have a recommendation for a REST client wrapper for .NET similar to ActiveResource?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby well enough, but you could try the [WCF REST Starter Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee391967.aspx) for a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This has some information about writing your own. 
[Guidance for writing a wrapper for a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589179/guidance-for-writing-a-wrapper-for-a-rest-api)

Here's a simple tutorial on writing your own in just 4 easy steps using wcf
http://howto-notes.blogspot.com/2009/04/wcf-rest-client.html